# Can't open pdf file in client application

Tags: 2010, pdf, client

I want to open a PDF file directly to my client application(Nuance Power PDF), but the file still opens in browser despite my selection from Advanced Settings (SharePoint 2010).

I am an user, not admin.

So how can I force SharePoint to open directly to Nuance?

Many thanks for any kind of support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
In Adobe Acrobat (or Adobe Reader) in Edit -> Preferences -> Internet uncheck  "Display PDF in browser".